# How to render bullet in pdf using css?

Tags: pdf, css

I have visualforce page render as pdf.I want to put bullet.The bullet works well in web but not display in pdf.

```
<apex:page controller="MyController" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false">
    <head>
         <style>
         ul.bulletgreen li{
             list-style-type: disc;
             font-size:60px;
             color:green;
         }
         </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="grey-table" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th>Name</th>
                   <th>Position</th>
                   <th>Job Function</th>
                   <th>View of Company</th>
                </tr> 
            </thead>
            <tbody >
                <apex:repeat value="{!myList}" var="list" >
                    <tr>
                        <td>{!list.Name__c}</td>
                        <td>{!list.Position__c}</td>
                        <td>{!list.Salary__c}</td>
                        <td>
                            <ul class="bulletgreen">
                                <li >Test</li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>
                <apex:outputPanel layout="none">
                    <tr><td colspan="4" align="center" >No Record(s) Found</td></tr>
               </apex:outputPanel>                      
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

Actually before I try for bullet, I also had try this. My objective is to get filled-circle icon, but it came out square.

```
.circle {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

How to render this circle filled with color in pdf? I tried bullet and css, any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PDF renderer has pretty poor support for certain areas of CSS, and I wouldn't be all that surprised if it didn't support `list-style-type`.

You may well have more luck just using putting a unicode bullet point in (the HTML `&bull;`should do it: •) into the start of each list item. This should still be able to get it's colour from the CSS class.